# Can I get the Linux "max user processes" in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, unit-testing

I'm investigating some unit test failures. The tests pass on an old build server that's been hand-configured (and not documented). I'm trying to run them in a clean virtual machine.

My latest problem is a unit test that creates 10K threads.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    final Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() { ... });
    threads.add(thread);
    thread.start();
}
```

Well, the max user processes in the clean environment is only 4K.

```
$ ulimit -u
4096
```

I was wondering if there's some way for Java to get at that limit. The test really doesn't need 10K, it just needs some arbitrarily large number.

Answer (score 1):

You could call ulimit directly:

[Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Oh, that's interesting... not cross-platform on it's own (we have Win and Linux devs here), but a start.

Comment: also note you'll have to exec bash with the proper options (there are probably some other examples on SO), since ulimit isn't a standalone executable

Comment: Windows thread limits are... complicated.  It depends on the version and whether it's 32 or 64 bit, amongst other things.  I don't know of a simple ulimit.  See here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2009/07/08/3261309.aspx

Comment: thats very interesting - even after all these years i had no clue about the ... apparently dynamic nature of windows thread limits, thank you!